# When using MultiParamTypeClasses, do you need to use every type in every class function

Tags: haskell

When I use MultiParamTypeClasses, I can create class functions that ignore one of the type parameters (ie- like "identity" below).

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data Add = Add
data Mul = Mul

class Test a b where
    identity::a

instance Test Int Add where
    identity = 0

instance Test Int Mul where
    identity = 1
```

(this is a stripped down version, of course in the full program there would be other functions that would use "b").

The example compiles, but I can never access identity!

```
main = do
    putStrLn (show (identity::Int))
```

leads to "No instance for (Test Int b0) arising from a use of 'identity'.

Is there a way to access identity?  If not, shouldn't the compiler forbid me from ever creating a class function that doesn't use all type parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If not, shouldn't the compiler forbid me from ever creating a class function that doesn't use all type parameters?

Perhaps. Indeed you'll never be able to use such a class method. But as the error occurs always at compile-time, it's not really dangerous.

Fixes that work in some similar cases (not in yours, though):

- Make the undetermined type variable *functionally dependent* on one of the others.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
  class Group_FD g p | g->p where
    identity :: g
  ```

  This could be used perhaps like

  ```
  data Nat = One | Succ Nat

  instance Group_FD Nat Mult where
    identity = One

  instance Group_FD Int Add where
    identity = 0
  ```

  But it's obviously not possible to make multiple instances with the same `g` element this way.
- Define a seperate class with only one parameter for the methods that depend only on that. Then make this class a constraint ("superclass") on the other one, to "import" methods:

  ```
  class Identity i where
    identity :: i
  class (Identity i) => Test i y
  ```

  that's no use at all for your application though, since you *want* the behaviour of `identity` to depend on the Phantom type variable.

To achieve your goal, you must somehow pass the information of which instance you want. One way to achieve this is phantom arguments:

```
class Group_PA g p where
  identity :: p -> g

instance Group_PA Int Add where
  identity _ = 0

instance Group_PA Int Mult where
  identity _ = 1
```

You could then use that like

> GHCi> identity Add :: Int
> 0
>   
> GHCi> identity Mult :: Int
> 1

Perhaps more idiomatic would actually be to make the flag types empty

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
data Add
data Mult
```

> GHCi> identity (undefined :: Add) :: Int
> 0
>   
> GHCi> identity (undefined :: Mult) :: Int
> 1

This makes it clearer that the phantom argument actually carries no runtime information, just controls what instance the compiler chooses.

Admittedly, this is pretty ugly.

The **right**™ solution is to make newtype wrappers to contain the phantom information. In fact, such wrappers are already in the standard libraries: [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v%3aSum) and [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aProduct).

Comment: See my answer for a way such a class definition could be used, without having to change the class definition. But, agreed, that usage is pretty useless.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention Proxy when you talk about phantom arguments?

Comment: @bennofs: honestly, I consider proxies even more ugly than stray `undefined` arguments in your code.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer because it offers great practical advice, although I think bennofs' answer also adds some important info to the discussion, too bad I can't split the credit.  I am still curious what the proxy stuff is though....

Comment: @jamshidh: you can _upvote_ bennofs' answer, that also gives credit (10 pts, compared to 15 for an accept). — As for the Proxy stuff... you add yet another `data GroupSelector p = SelectGroup` with a trivial constructor, but also with a type argument so the constructor has a polymorphic type. Then you can do `identity (SelectGroup :: GroupSelector Add) :: Int`. Which amounts to pretty much the same result as with your non-empty `Add` and `Mult` data types, but in a much more roundabout way.     (Proxies do have some not-completely unreasonable applications, but those are rare.)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `FlexibleInstances`, it's possible to change the instance definition so that identity may be used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Add = Add
data Mul = Mul

class Test a b where
    identity::a

instance Test Int b where
    identity = 0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ (identity :: Int)
```

Because instances could be defined in an other file and then only that file would require the use of `FlexibleInstances`, GHC cannot disallow class declarations that don't use all their type variables in general.

If you want instances for different `b's`, then you have to use `FunctionalDependencies`.